# Adding Unicode/UTF8 chars to a ncurses display in C

Tags: c, utf-8, ncurses

I'm attempting to add wchar_t Unicode characters to an ncurses display in C.

I have an array:

```
wchar_t characters[]={L'\uE030', L'\uE029'}; // containing 2 thai letters, for example
```

And I later try to add a wchar_t from the array to the ncurses display with:

```
add_wch(characters[0]);
```

To provide a bit more info, doing this with ASCII works ok, using:

```
char characters[]={'A', 'B'};

// and later...

addch(characters[0]);
```

To setup the locale, I add the include...

```
#include <locale.h>

// in main()
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"C-UTF-8");
```

The ncurses include is:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
```

Compiling with :

(edit: added c99 standard, for universal char name support.)

```
gcc -o ncursesutf8 ncursesutf8.c -lm -lncurses -Wall -std=c99
```

I get the following compilation warning (of course the executable will fail):

```
ncursesutf8.c:48: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘add_wch’
```

I've tried just using `addch` which appears to be macro'ed to work with wchar_t but when I do that the Unicode chars do not show up, instead they show as ASCII chars instead.

Any thoughts?

I am using OS X Snow Leopard, 10.6.6

Edit: removed error on `wchar_t []` assignment to use `L'\u0E30'` instead of `L"\u0E30"` etc.
 I've also updated the compiler settings to use C99 (to add universal char name support). both changes do not fix the problem.

Still no answers on this, does anyone know how to do Unicode ncurses `addchar` (add_wchar?)  ?! Help!

Comment: Also note that you should never pass any string but `""` to `setlocale`. Passing `""` results in getting the configured/system locale, which should be UTF-8 based on any modern system. Names like `"C-UTF-8"` are not portable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The wide character support is handled by ncursesw. Depending on your distro, ncurses may or may not point there (seemingly not in yours).

Try using `-lncursesw` instead of `-lncurses`.

Also, for the locale, try calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`

Comment: Also, note that the call to `setlocale` must precede `initscr()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is **not** 2 characters:

```
wchar_t characters[]={L"\uE030", L"\uE029"};
```

You're trying to initialize `wchar_t` (integer) values with pointers, which should result in an error from the compiler. Either use:

```
wchar_t characters[]={L'\uE030', L'\uE029'};
```

or

```
wchar_t characters[]=L"\uE030\uE029";
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't solve the problem, see my edits above. Any ideas?

Comment: @R ... any chance you have an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

`cchar_t` is defined as:

```
typedef struct {
    attr_t  attr;
    wchar_t chars[CCHARW_MAX];
} cchar_t;
```

so you might try:

```
int add_wchar(int c)
{
    cchar_t t = {
        0, // .attr
        {c, 0} // not sure how .chars works, so best guess
    };
    return add_wch(t);
}
```

not at all tested, but should work.

Comment: I'll give it a try, hope you guess well ;)

Comment: Well, that didn't work, CCHARW_MAX is undefined, I really have no idea how you came up with this, some explanation would be helpful. I also had to add the `cchar_t` struct to the source, they way you  put it, inferred that it was already defined (presumably in ncurses).

Comment: Wait, do you *have* add_wch? My documentation has it, but it apparently isnt defined in my ncurses.h.

Comment: I have `add_wch` but it doesn't appear to work (terminal output is `?` in place of thai unicode chars I'm using, which show up ok otherwise, e.g. if I input them directly into the terminal prompt.)

Comment: Okay, I'm stumped then. (The warning in your post seems to imply that you don't have `add_wch`, are you still getting that?) Maybe post/link your ncurses.h?

Answer (score 1):

Did you define `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` before including the ncurses header?

Comment: I ended up doing this in Lisp instead of C. :)