# Print braille characters in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, braille

I attempted to print braille characters in ncurses.

This is my code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

char *str = 
    " ⠁⠂⠃⠄⠅⠆⠇⠈⠉⠊⠋⠌⠍⠎⠏\n"
    "⠐⠑⠒⠓⠔⠕⠖⠗⠘⠙⠚⠛⠜⠝⠞⠟\n"
    "⠠⠡⠢⠣⠤⠥⠦⠧⠨⠩⠪⠫⠬⠭⠮⠯\n"
    "⠰⠱⠲⠳⠴⠵⠶⠷⠸⠹⠺⠻⠼⠽⠾⠿\n";


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    initscr();
    printw("%s", str);
    getch();
    printf("%s", curses_version());
    endwin();
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
 ?~A?~B?~C?~D?~E?~F?~G?~H?~I?~J?~K?~L?~M?~N?~O
?~P?~Q?~R?~S?~T?~U?~V?~W?~X?~Y?~Z?~[?~\?~]?~^?~_
⠠⠡⠢⠣⠤⠥⠦⠧⠨⠩⠪⠫⠬⠭⠮⠯
⠰⠱⠲⠳⠴⠵⠶⠷⠸⠹⠺⠻⠼⠽⠾⠿
```

How do I output all characters correctly?

Update: I also tried `printf` which seems to work, `addstr` produces the same output as `printw`.

If I change the locale with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` I get the output:

```
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
 P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _
⠠⠡⠢⠣⠤⠥⠦⠧⠨⠩⠪⠫⠬⠭⠮⠯
⠰⠱⠲⠳⠴⠵⠶⠷⠸⠹⠺⠻⠼⠽⠾⠿
```

Comment: so, does it work with `stdio`? Looks like some encoding problem, but could be a bug in your ncurses' handling of multi-byte characters.

Comment: It seems to work with `stdio`, I am running version 6.0.20160910 of ncurses

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249265/8051589?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you, I called `setlocale()` after `initscr()`, so it didn't work. If I call if before, it works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞ with Ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373027/how-can-i-print-%ef%be%9f%e3%83%ae%ef%be%9f-with-ncurses)

Comment: do we close as a duplicate? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some experimentation, I found what is probably wrong:

1. Your program uses the `C` locale by default. This assumes ASCII encoding. It's not a problem when you output multi-byte characters with `stdio`, because these functions just deliver the bytes *as is* to the console. But `ncurses` actually uses the locale, so it can know things like how many bytes make a character (important for exact positioning) etc. Change your program as following:

   ```
   #include <curses.h>
   #include <locale.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       // initialize locale to system's default:
       setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

       // now init and use curses ...
   ```
2. If you still get garbled output, your system's `libncurses` doesn't handle unicode. In that case, link `ncursesw` instead of `ncurses` and you should be done.