# Let nCurses handle UTF8 character by terminal

Tags: c, ncurses

Ncurses have whole family of print functions for wide characters: https://linux.die.net/man/3/mvwaddnwstr

The problem with those is that it depends glibc, so if some UTF-8 character were yet not added to glibc those won't be printed properly example is: ✅

The solution I can see is to let ncurses handle displaying the character by "terminal", what I mean by that is that if we would have some sort of print function that would accept hex UTF-8 string and let terminal find correct font like below snippet do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    write(1, "\xe2\x9c\x85", 9);
}
```

Is is possible with nCurses?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373027/how-can-i-print-ﾟヮﾟ-with-ncurses

Comment: Nope my problem is not that I don’t know how to print UTF8 with ncurses but with the fact that ncurses just won’t print all UTF8 characters correctly if those are not added to current glibc version

Comment: are you using the wide form?

Comment: Yes wide form and proper locale and most of wide characters works fine but some don’t like the one I have posted

Comment: If the width of a character isn't known, ncurses will ignore it.  You'll have to learn how to configure locale data in glibc if you want a solution.

Comment: Exactly and for this one is -1 but is there a way I can do stuff in ncurses to print char by letting terminal figure out the font like in my example

Comment: @ThomasDickey can you give some more info what do you mean by " learn how to configure locale data in glibc" ?

Comment: There's an example of what's needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23533623/1566221

Comment: By the way, ncurses *does* rely on whatever terminal emulator you use to find fonts and render them. All it needs is the wcwidth so that it can predict how much space the character will occupy.

Comment: Wow that's answer is super! Thx