# How to print Unicode with NCurses?

Tags: unicode, encoding, ncurses, raku

This prints

```
�~X�
```

How could I get the unicode `☺` instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use NCurses;

my $win = initscr;
my Str $s = "\x[263a]";
printw( $s );
nc_refresh;
while getch() < 0 {};
endwin;
```

Comment: Can't help you, when I run `LANG=C perl6 -e 'use NCurses; printw( "\x[263a]");'` I get a coredump.

Comment: This is related to C, but might be helpful, in terms of setting Locale and such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703168/adding-unicode-utf8-chars-to-a-ncurses-display-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the same as you - turns out just needed to set locale;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use NCurses;

use NativeCall;
my int32 constant LC_ALL = 6;          # From locale.h
my sub setlocale(int32, Str) returns Str is native(Str) { * }

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
my $win = initscr;
my Str $s = "\x[263a]";
printw( $s );
nc_refresh;
while getch() < 0 {};
endwin;
```

That puts a smile on my face... and screen. ☺