# Print long unicode in ncurses

Tags: c, unicode, ncurses

I need to print some unicode characters for my game on terminal, some like this, `\U0001F0A1`, and my code

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    printw("\U0001F0A1");
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

and all it print out is blank screen, but when i tried with printf, it can print a card out normally.

Comment: Try `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");`

Comment: Also `printw(L"\U0001F0A1");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703168/adding-unicode-utf8-chars-to-a-ncurses-display-in-c

Comment: @sunqingyao i tried your codes but it doesn't show anything up

Comment: @Morovaille the answer in the post doesn't help at all

Comment: @UyHà are you sure this utf-8 code is valid ? I tried this solution with an unicode char and it worked.

Comment: @Morovaille i tried with printf and it prints out find, but when it comes to ncurses, it won't print anything

Comment: Did you try with `printw(L"\U0001F0A1");` and link with `-lncursesw` ?

Comment: @Morovaille yes i did but still nothing prints out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109265/discussion-between-uy-ha-and-morovaille).

Comment: Try `-lncursesw` instead of `-lncurses`. This works on my system, YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

The likely problem is this: ncurses uses `wcwidth` to determine the width of the character, and `printf` does not check.  The locale information on your computer is too old to give proper results.

Checking with my Debian testing, this works (using the sample program given in the question, compiling/linking with ncursesw) - see screenshot:

[image]

According to [fileformat-info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f0a1/index.htm), this comes from Unicode 6.0 (2010).  Depending on what system you are using, e.g., Debian or Ubuntu, that may be "recent".

ncurses requires correct `wcwidth` locale information while `printf` does not use the wcwidth-information.  If your locale information is too old, `wcwidth` returns a negative value, telling ncurses that the character is nonprinting.  In that case, ncurses will display a blank.

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're saying here. Are you saying the OP's system may or may not support this? Or that the code is fine? Or that the code is not fine? That the OP needs to use `printf` instead? What is it that you're trying to say?

Comment: OP's system may not support it: ncurses requires correct wcwidth locale information while printf does not use the wcwidth-information.

Comment: Okay I guess I was too subtle but what I'm trying to say is that you should edit your answer to be clearer about what your recommendation is, because at the moment I'm not convinced it's really an answer.

Comment: I used the given example without changing it.

Comment: so how can i let the locale know the length i need to display ?

Comment: The people who maintain the locale runtime are supposed to do that for you.