# C99 UTF8 characters with ncurses

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, c99, ncurses

I am playing around with `ncurses` and have encountered a problem. I want to draw a simple box with Unicode block characters (U+2588, █), but I cannot get it to display properly:

[image]

As you can see, the character I want is displayed as `~H`.

I followed the intructions from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703168/adding-unicode-utf8-chars-to-a-ncurses-display-in-c) to a tee. Minimal working example:

```c
#include <locale.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // must be caled before initscr
    WINDOW *win = initscr();

    int w, h;
    getmaxyx(win, h, w);
    
    // should fill the left half of the 
    // terminal window with filled block characters
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w/2; j++) {
            mvaddch(x, y, L'\u2588');
        }
    }

    refresh(); // show changes
    getch();   // wait for user input
    endwin();  // kill window
    
    return 1;
}
```

Compiled with:

```sh
gcc main.c -o main -std=c99 -lncurses
```

[image: minimal working example demonstration]

My PC locale is `en_US.UTF-8` and I'm using the suckless terminal which is of course [perfectly capable of dislaying utf8:](https://serverfault.com/questions/13898/how-to-find-out-if-a-terminal-supports-utf-8)

[image: st utf8 demonstration]

It's a very simple program and I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual page gives a [short overview of data-types](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Routine-and-Argument-Names) which are used for function parameters.

In the example, `L'\u2588'` is a *wide character*, which would be stored in a **`wchar_t`** type.

- The [`mvaddch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) function uses a `chtype`, which is not the same as **`wchar_t`**.
- The curses function which corresponds to `mvaddch` is `mvadd_wch`, which uses a third type (`cchar_t`).
- You could either convert that *wide character* to a `cchar_t` using [`setcchar`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getcchar.3x.html), or
- You could store the value in an array of `wchar_t` and pass **that** to [mvaddwstr](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html).